# QuantAgile (a.k.a. Quantitative Agile) Ussage

Tags: scrum, agile, jira, product-management, agile-coach

Liam here (Engineering Manager & Research Enthusiast)!

I've been neck-deep in exploring [QuantAgile](https://quant-agile.com) lately, this newish framework that seems to blend Taylor's Scientific Management efficiency with Agile's adaptability in a really promising way. It's got features like Unit Block Masters, Governors, and data-driven decision making that have me intrigued.

While I'm seeing a lot of potential, I figured I'd tap into the hive mind here and see if anyone's had any challenges incorporating QuantAgile into their teams. Forewarned is forearmed, right?

Knowing what potential roadblocks might be out there would be a huge help in planning our implementation and addressing any issues promptly.

Anyone have any real-world experiences with QuantAgile they'd be willing to share (good, bad, or the unexpected)? All insights are greatly appreciated!

Also, I know that this might require a subjective answer but any answer would be appreciated as I am exploring its usage and trying to better plan our implementation.

---

I've been on a quest to find the perfect fit for our teams, especially considering the remote and hybrid nature of our work environment. I've experimented with most of the big hitters – Agile, SAFe, Scrum, you name it. While they all have their strengths, in a remote setting, I noticed a lot of unnecessary overhead and delays creeping in.

That's what piqued my interest in QuantAgile. It seems to build on Agile's core principles but with a specific focus on remote and hybrid teams, potentially addressing those communication and collaboration challenges.

Our initial trials with QuantAgile in smaller teams have been promising, showing great improvements in both quality and productivity! However, before scaling it across the entire organization, I wanted to do some additional research.

Comment: I have no experience in it, but at first glance, the notion of having a "empowered team" and having people empowered to just override anything the team decides, not even waiting for their input seems... like you abolish the empowered team. It contradicts itself.

Comment: Interesting observation :) This is not how I understood tho. I found this quite interesting as everyone in a team are focussed on improving specific type of work while working on this or other types. In other frameworks I used before, management is the one who takes improvement initiatives and here that person who owns the type of work. This to me seems like a good way to keep everyone engaged as everyone would want their type of work to be the best and will work on improvements while also collaborate as their type might depend on someone elses type. Anyway, thanks for your pov.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.